# JavaScript Error only with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Anyone knows what is this message at Chrome?

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at chrome-extension://nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef/content.js:4:113
at extensions::messaging:320:11
at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
at Event.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:386:22)
at Event.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:371:27)
at Event.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:392:17)
at dispatchOnDisconnect (extensions::messaging:280:27)
```

Additionaly when I go to content.js:4:113 I get

```
console.clear()});chrome.runtime.sendMessage({_registerTab:!0,url:window.location.href,protocol:k},function(a){a.url&&(window.location.href=a.url);l=a.id})};
```

Comment: It's not Chrome, it's the Chrome extension [nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef?hl=en), which appears to be some PHP console.

Comment: `a.url` is what is creating a problem here. Object `a` isn't defined.